# Beginner c++ programmer: Stuck writing a class

Tags: c++

I have to write a program for an exercise in classes, but I'm completely lost. I have a bit of experience programming in java, so the switch to c++ syntax is confusing me quite a bit.

The prompt is:  Write the definition of a class  ,   swimmingPool  , to implement the proper-ties of a swimming pool. Your class   should have the instance variables to store the length (in feet), width (in feet), depth (in feet), the rate (in gallons per minute) at which the water is filling the pool, and the rate (in gallons per minute) at which the water is draining from the pool. Add appropriate constructors to initialize the instance variables. Also add member functions to do the following: determine the amount of water needed to fill an empty or partially filled pool, determine the time needed to completely or partially fill or empty the pool, and add or drain water for a specific amount of time.

I am getting several build errors. Understand that what I have right now is not complete. Here is my progress so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    swimmingPool mySwimmingPool;
    int length, width, depth, rateToFill, rateToDrain;

    cout << "Pool Data: " << endl;
    cout << mySwimmingPool.getPoolData(5, 12,6) << endl;

}


class swimmingPool
{
public:
    int getPoolData(int, int, int);
    int getAmountOfWater();
    int getTime();
    int incrementWater(double time);
    int decrementWater(double time);
    int poolCapacity();
    swimmingPool();
    swimmingPool(int l, int w, int d, int rateFill, int rateDrain);

private:
    int length;
    int width;
    int depth;
    int rateToFill;
    int rateToDrain;
};

swimmingPool::swimmingPool()
{
    length = 0;
    width = 0;
    depth = 0;
    rateToFill = 0;
    rateToDrain = 0;
}

swimmingPool::swimmingPool(int l, int w, int d, int rateFill, int rateDrain)
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
    depth = d;
    rateToFill = rateFill;
    rateToDrain = rateDrain;
}

int swimmingPool::getPoolData(int l, int w, int d)
{
    length = l;
    width = w; 
    depth = d;

    cout << "length: " << l << endl;
    cout << "width: " << w << endl;
    cout << "depth: " << d << endl;
}

int swimmingPool::getAmountOfWater()
{
    return (length * width * depth);
}

int swimmingPool::getTime()
{
    return getAmountOfWater() / rateToFill;
}

int swimmingPool::incrementWater(double time)
{
    return rateToFill * time;
}

int swimmingPool::decrementWater(double time)
{
    return rateToDrain * time;
}
```

Comment: If you are completely lost you should speak to your teacher about it.

Comment: 1. Declarations need to be ordered before you use them.  Move the `swimmingPool` class to be before `main`.

Comment: 2. Your `getPoolData` function says it returns an `int`, but you are not returning any value.  If your function doesn't *need* to return a value, declare it as returning `void`.

Comment: 3. If your method *calls* `cout`, don't use the `operator<<` and `cout`.  Just call it.

Comment: 4. You have truncation issues.  You are returning an expression of the type "`int` * `double`".  Because you told the compiler the function returns `int`, the expression will be truncated.  Is this what you wanted?  Or did you want to return a `double` instead?

Comment: 5. Integer division:  `getAmountOfWater() / rateToFill`.  Dividing an `int` by an `int` results in an `int`, not a floating point value.  For example, `3/2 == 1`.

Comment: 6. The `rateToFill` denominator is not checked for 0 before dividing.  From *mathematics* division by zero is not defined (don't do it).

Comment: @LukeG -`mySwimmingPool` is initialized by the default constructor.

Comment: If you have build errors, then specify the exact text of those build errors.

Answer (score 2):

If your program return type of functions are not correct. Please see your modified code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class swimmingPool
{
public:
    void getPoolData(int, int, int);
    int getAmountOfWater();
    double getTime();
    double incrementWater(double time);
    double decrementWater(double time);
    int poolCapacity();
    swimmingPool();
    swimmingPool(int l, int w, int d, int rateFill, int rateDrain);

private:
    int length;
    int width;
    int depth;
    int rateToFill;
    int rateToDrain;
};

swimmingPool::swimmingPool()
{
    length = 0;
    width = 0;
    depth = 0;
    rateToFill = 0;
    rateToDrain = 0;
}

swimmingPool::swimmingPool(int l, int w, int d, int rateFill, int rateDrain)
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
    depth = d;
    rateToFill = rateFill;
    rateToDrain = rateDrain;
}

//If function do not return any value then return type should be void
void swimmingPool::getPoolData(int l, int w, int d)
{
    length = l;
    width = w; 
    depth = d;

    cout << "length: " << l << endl;
    cout << "width: " << w << endl;
    cout << "depth: " << d << endl;
}

int swimmingPool::getAmountOfWater()
{
    return (length * width * depth);
}

double swimmingPool::getTime()
{
    return getAmountOfWater() / rateToFill; //This value is double not int. if you convert double to int data maybe loss 
}

double swimmingPool::incrementWater(double time)
{
    return rateToFill * time; //This value is double not int. if you convert double to int data maybe loss 
}

double swimmingPool::decrementWater(double time)
{
    return rateToDrain * time; //This value is double not int. if you convert double to int data maybe loss 
}


int main()
{
    swimmingPool mySwimmingPool;
    //You don't need this variables
    //int length, width, depth, rateToFill, rateToDrain;

    cout << "Pool Data: " << endl;
    mySwimmingPool.getPoolData(5, 12,6);
    return 0;
}
```